# Dynamic SQL in Poweruilder 12.6

Tags: powerbuilder

I created a function using Dynamic SQL in Powerbuilder 12.6 as follows, the database is SQL Anywhere 10.0

```
// function name :of_encrypt()
// parameters: string as_info, as_passwd

String ls_sql
blob lblb_encrypted

// two types all report error message
// there are two parameters in the SQL.
//ls_sql = "select encrypt('?','?')" // add apostrophe
ls_sql = "select encrypt(?,?)"       // not apostrophe

DECLARE C1 DYNAMIC CURSOR FOR SQLSA;
PREPARE SQLSA FROM :ls_sql;
OPEN DYNAMIC C1 USING :as_info,:as_passwd;  // this line reported error, not allowed two parameters?
FETCH C1 INTO :lblb_encrypted;
CLOSE C1;
Return lblb_encrypted
```

After I use this function to test like follows:

```
of_encrypt("software","passwd")
```

Powerbuilder give the error message:

```
Error:Database command not successfully prepared at line 13 in function of_encrypt.
```

How to find the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only ever seen the **USING** statement used to indicate the database transaction object so i'm wondering if that's an issue.

i think something like this might work:

```
ls_sql = "select encrypt('" + as_info + "','" + as_passwd + "')"     

DECLARE C1 DYNAMIC CURSOR FOR SQLSA;
PREPARE SQLSA FROM :ls_sql;
OPEN DYNAMIC C1;
FETCH C1 INTO :lblb_encrypted;
CLOSE C1;
```

or if you don't require dynamic sql:

```
SELECT  encrypt(:as_info , :as_passwd)
INTO        :lblb_encrypted
FROM        dummy;
```

Comment: Thanks for your great reply!

Answer (score 0):

using SELECTBLOB

```
    Blob lblb_encrypted
    string as_info, as_passwd
    SELECTBLOB encrypt(:as_info, :as_passwd) INTO :lblb_encrypted FROM table;
```